# Sentry Raven stand alone client windows

Tags: windows, python

I started to use the Sentry ( https://getsentry.com/ )  and its quite awesome.
The thing that i am not able to find is a stand alone somewhat "minified" raven client for windows.
Im able to write python code and just looked into the python-raven, i tried to build it with pyinstaller but it seems that this is not the right solution.

**I need** some **way** to **run Raven stand alone** with the **logging message as an parameter**, so that i could use it in the whole windows service management.

Do i can't see the wood for the trees??

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic. You may want to consider rewording your question before it ends up closed.

Comment: @CharlieRB read my question again... i need a way to use Raven stand alone. Without installing python + twisted + more crap on every windows machine.

Comment: According to [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic), it's off-topic because you say *"I need some program that i could run..."*. Is that not asking for a recommendation? If all you are asking is "How can I run Raven stand alone?", then why don't you ask that? That would not be off-topic.